# Disable debugging info in intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA is suddenly showing debugging info after each line of code, how do I disable this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it by unchecking *Show values in editor* in the Settings menu in Debug view. Here is a screenshot in case you can't locate it:

[image: Debug view menu]

Note that you might need to restart your debugging session in order for the change to take effect.